# django centos xapian haystack

Tags: django, django-haystack, centos5, xapian

I just went through a bit of an installation process with django-haystack and xapian on my root user and eventually my other user and all the responses seem to be okay.

even when I am in my `other_user` in shell, and running `import xapian` and `import haystack` it all runs without any errors.

As soon as I uncomment `#'haystack',` in my settings file. and restart apache it throws an error

```
The 'xapian' backend requires the installation of 'xapian'.
```

installed xapian-core, xapian-bindings

Any ideas why it would still not work?

HERE is my configure

```
./configure --prefix=/home/appel/xapian-install XAPIAN_CONFIG=/home/appel/xapian-install/bin/xapian-config PYTHON=/opt/python2.6/bin/python2.6 PYTHON_LIB=/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6 --with-python --without-ruby --without-tcl --without-php
```

Comment: I had the same problem. The issue was with the installation of Xapian targeting the incorrect version of python. Are you running two versions of python in parrallel?

Comment: the basic installation of centos dictates that it's python2.4 I have python2.6 running and my ./configure I have added above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting Xapian from apt-get / pip repository doesn't give you everything you need.
With the parallel installation the xapian-bindings were the wrong version and could not bind correctly to the used python.

I'm not sure what they do specifically.

Ensure you install the correct version of the bindings for your associated python26 -
Once this is done, its very easy to install and use Xapian and Haystack

http://xapian.org/download

If you find the exact download required - please share it as I've lost it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: so you mean, use yum instead to install all the versions?

Comment: Hmm. I don't think I do. As I'm aware - you can only get the correct bindings by scouring the internet. At least when I tried, I couldn't find it on Yum repo.